# Codeigniter/Postgresql: Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

This thing is been bothering me of a couple of days and I haven't been able to fix it. I have this registration form. And when submitting this form This error keeps popping up and the reason for this happening is the registration details are not getting inserted into the database.

I am using Postgresql as the database system. But the data is not getting inserted. I am really frustrated with this. I will post my model, controller below, If anything is required please let me know.

**Controller:**

```
    function register()
{

    //set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_name', 'Customer Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address1', 'Address 1', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address2', 'Address 2', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'State', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[gkb_users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|is_unique[gkb_users.username]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]|md5');

    //validate form input
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
    //fails
    $this->loadHeader($this);

    //load sidebar
    $this->loadSidebar($this);

    //load middle content
    $this->load->view('register_view'); 

    //load footer
    $this->loadFooter($this);
    }
    else
    {
        //insert the user registration details into database
        $data = array(
            'cust_name' => $this->input->post('customer_name'),
            'address1' => $this->input->post('address1'),
            'address2' => $this->input->post('address2'),
            'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
            'state_code' => $this->input->post('state'),
            'country_code' => $this->input->post('country'),
            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
            'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        );

        // insert form data into database
        if ($this->user_model->insertUser($data))
        {
            // send email
            if ($this->user_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email')))
            {
                // successfully sent mail
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Registered! Please confirm the mail sent to your Email-ID!!!</div>');
                redirect('user/register');
            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('user/register');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
            redirect('user/register');
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
    function insertUser($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
```

I will be really grateful if I can solve this. Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
    public function checkfrontendUser($username,$passwd)
{
    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE (
                    `username` = '".$username."'
                    OR
                    `email` = '".$username."'
              )
              AND `password` = '".$passwd."'
    ";      
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $result->result_array();
    }       
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: show your method where use `num_rows()`

Comment: I have edited the question and inserted it there

Comment: `var_dump($result)` see what it returns. May be query issue

Comment: I will have a look

Comment: It will not be able to select anything and print it in `var_dump()` Because nothing is getting inserted

Answer (score 0):

Mainly this can happen for database connection problem or your query is failing. No matter how you are connecting your DB whether through `database.php` or `$this->load->database()`. double check your Db credentials.

secondly you may check as

```
if($result !== FALSE){
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0){
        return $result->result_array();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Problem I am new to postgresql and I have a feeling this is the reason why I am facing such a problem.